# Solving for a variable under $\Gamma(z)$

Tags: special-functions, gamma-function

My friend came to see me regarding some calculation in probability where he would like to know if it is possible to solve for a variable analytically under the gamma function. By this I mean say we are given the value of some quantity $x$, such that

$x = \dfrac{\Gamma(1 + \frac{2}{k})}{\left(\Gamma(1 + \frac{1}{k})\right)^2}$

I would like to solve this for some real number $k$. I can use the factorial to manipulate this expression and get

$x = \dfrac{(\frac{2}{k})!}{{\left(\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)!\right)}^2      }$

If (a big if) I can make the substitution $n = \frac{1}{k}$, this would be equal to the central binomial coefficient. However I don't think this is possible as $\frac{1}{k}$ is not an integer in general.

What else can I do? Thanks.

Comment: @DJC Why is there a $2 + 2/k$ in there? Did you mean $1 + 2/k$?

Comment: I will delete my other comment.  Less explicitly, but helpful (I hope):  The Beta-function is related to the Gamma function by  $$B(x_1,x_2) = \frac{\Gamma(x_1) \Gamma(x_2)}{\Gamma(x_1 + x_2)}.$$  Setting $x_1 = x_2 = 1 + \frac{1}{k}$ gives $$\frac{1}{x} = \left(2 + \frac{2}{k}\right) B\left(1 + \frac{1}{k}, 1 +\frac{1}{k}\right).$$

Comment: Thanks, I wills see what I can work with from there.

Comment: Considering how difficult it is to solve similar equations for Factorials, solving these gamma function equations are certainly not possible analytically. For most purposes using Stirling's approximation to solve for $x$ numerically should suffice.

Comment: A closed-form solution looks unlikely to me. You'll definitely have to use a numerical method like Newton-Raphson for this.

Comment: @D B Lim what is the range for $x$?

Comment: I remember that $x$ was the mean squared divided by the standard deviation squared of something, I do not do statistics and was trying to help my friend out. About the range, I can ask him tomorrow. Is it really important?

Comment: @RagibZaman You're probably right, the answer below goes something along those lines.

Comment: @Andrew I found out that $x$ ranges from 1 to 2.

Comment: @D B Lim then series expansion, as proposed by Sasha, should work well enough. Also computer algebra systems  has procedures for numerical roots finding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $u = \frac{1}{k}$. Using duplication formula for the numerator:
$$
  \Gamma\left( 2 u + 1\right) = \frac{4^u}{\sqrt{\pi}} \Gamma\left(u + 1\right)\Gamma\left(u + \frac{1}{2}\right)
$$
we rewrite your equation as 
$$
    x = \frac{4^u}{\sqrt{\pi}} \frac{\Gamma\left(u + \frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(u + 1\right)}
$$
This form is helpful if $u$ is large, because $\frac{\Gamma\left(u + \frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(u + 1\right)} \sim \sqrt{u} + o(1)$

Thus if $x$ is large, equation becomes $x = 4^u \sqrt{\frac{u}{\pi}}$, which can be solved exactly $u = \frac{W(4 x^2 \pi \log x )}{4 \log 2}$, where $W$ is the Lambert W function.

If $u$ is small, series expansion works well:
$$
  \frac{4^u}{\sqrt{\pi}} \frac{\Gamma\left(u + \frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(u + 1\right)} \sim 1 + \frac{\pi^2}{6} u^2 - 2 \zeta(3) u^3 + \frac{19 \pi^4}{360} u^4 + o(u^4)
$$

Answer (score 0):

*Sorry to be late !*

Consider instead that you want to solve for $k$
$$\log\Bigg( \dfrac{\Gamma(1 + \frac{2}{k})}{\Big(\Gamma(1 + \frac{1}{k})\Big)^2}\Bigg)=y \qquad \text{with} \qquad y=\log(x)\qquad (x >1)$$ If $x$ is small, $k$ will be "large".

Using the expansion
$$\log (\Gamma (1+\epsilon))=-\gamma\,  \epsilon +\frac{\pi ^2 }{12}\epsilon ^2-\frac{\zeta (3)
  }{3} \epsilon ^3+\frac{\pi ^4}{360} \epsilon ^4+O\left(\epsilon^5\right)$$ you should end with
$$y=\frac{\pi ^2}{6 k^2}-\frac{2 \zeta (3)}{k^3}+\frac{7 \pi ^4}{180
   k^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^5}\right)$$

Using power series reversion
$$k=\frac{\pi }{\sqrt{6y}}-\frac{6 \zeta (3)}{\pi
   ^2}+\frac{\pi   \left(\frac{7}{10}-\frac{324 \zeta
   (3)^2}{\pi ^6}\right)}{\sqrt{6}}\sqrt{y}+O\left(y^1\right)$$

Trying for $x=1.1$, this gives $k=3.50795$ while the "exact" solution is $k=3.50284$.

If $x$ is large, $k$ being small, use Stirling approximation to obtain
$$y=\frac{2 \log (2)}{k}+\frac{1}{2} (\log (k)-\log (2 \pi )+\log
   (2))-\frac{k}{8}+O\left(k^3\right)$$ which cannot be inversed except if we ignore the $\frac{k}{8}$ term. In such a case, as @Sasha already wrote it,
$$k=-\frac{4 \log (2)}{W_{-1}\left(-\frac{4 e^{-2 y} \log (2)}{\pi}\right)}$$

Trying for $x=3$, this gives $k=0.769245$ while the "exact" solution is $k=0.720905$.

If we make the problem more general
$$\log\Bigg( \dfrac{\Gamma(1 + \frac{a}{k})}{\Big(\Gamma(1 + \frac{1}{k})\Big)^a}\Bigg)=y$$

$$y=\frac{\pi ^2 (a-1) a}{12 k^2}-\frac{a \left(a^2-1\right) \zeta
   (3)}{3 k^3}+\frac{\pi ^4 a \left(a^3-1\right)}{360
   k^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^5}\right)$$
$$k=\frac{\pi  \sqrt{(a-1) a}}{2 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{y}}-\frac{2 ((a+1)
   \zeta (3))}{\pi ^2}+$$ $$\frac{ \left(\pi ^6
   \left(a^2+a+1\right)-360 (a+1)^2 \zeta (3)^2\right)}{10
   \sqrt{3} \pi ^5 \sqrt{(a-1) a}}\sqrt{y}+O\left(y^1\right)$$